# How to read heap memory from the chunk returned by HeapProfiler in chrome remote protocol

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, heap-memory, chunks

I have developed a UI component which has its own UI (default) and API to be used. It has an function in the API named `refresh` that takes a data as a parameter and updates the visual.

Now I want to get the HeapMemory programatically. One use case is like

1. Fire the refresh fn 10 times and take the heap memory.
2. Do the 1st step for 5 times

I am using [this](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/) protocol to get all the information. I have been able to set up a WebSocket connection between the host and my client.

I send the following command to get the chunk (mentioned in the doc [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/HeapProfiler/#method-takeHeapSnapshot))

```
{"id":2, "method":"HeapProfiler.takeHeapSnapshot"}
```

Chrome sends me the following message back as output
[image]

My question is, what is chunk here? Is it chunk of data which lies in the heap? If that is the case what is all those numbers in the picture? Is it some object Id? How can I get the heap size occupied from the output.

I have little idea about how an object occupies a space in heap.